# javascript file not working when linking to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning how to build a game via a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ec8vSKJuZTk&t=2126s and CSS and JavaScript won't render on my browser (Chrome) when I open it. I am not sure why it won't link. The HTML works fine, but the JavaScript and CSS do not show up when I inspect element. However, the JavaScript file DOES work when I embed it within the HTML. Thanks!

I am editing in VisualStudio Code.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Matching Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" types="text/css" href="styles.css"></>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Score: <span id="result"></span></h3>

    <div id="grid"> </div>

    <script scr="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const cardArray = [
    {
    name: 'cactus',
    img: 'images/cactus.png',
    },
    {
    name: 'dino',
    img: 'images/dino.png',
    },
    {
    name: 'moon',
    img: 'images/moon.png',
    },
    {
    name: 'rabbit',
    img: 'images/rabbit.png',
    },
    {
        name: 'sun',
        img: 'images/sun.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'tree',
    img: 'images/tree.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'white',
    img: 'images/white.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'cactus',
    img: 'images/cactus.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'dino',
    img: 'images/dino.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'moon',
    img: 'images/moon.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'rabbit',
    img: 'images/rabbit.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'sun',
    img: 'images/sun.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'tree',
    img: 'images/tree.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'white',
    img: 'images/white.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'cactus',
    img: 'images/cactus.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'dino',
    img: 'images/dino.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'moon',
    img: 'images/moon.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'rabbit',
    img: 'images/rabbit.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'sun',
    img: 'images/sun.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'tree',
    img: 'images/tree.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'white',
    img: 'images/white.png'
    },
]

cardArray.sort(() => 8.5 - Math.random())

const gridDisplay = document.querySelector('#grid')

function createBoard() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const card = document.createElement('img')
        card.setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png')
        card.setAttribute('data-id', i)
        gridDisplay.appendChild(card)
    }
}
createBoard()
```

CSS:

```
#grid{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Current code as a snippet:

```js
const cardArray = [{
    name: 'cactus',
    img: 'images/cactus.png',
  },
  {
    name: 'dino',
    img: 'images/dino.png',
  },
  {
    name: 'moon',
    img: 'images/moon.png',
  },
  {
    name: 'rabbit',
    img: 'images/rabbit.png',
  },
  {
    name: 'sun',
    img: 'images/sun.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'tree',
    img: 'images/tree.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'white',
    img: 'images/white.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'cactus',
    img: 'images/cactus.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'dino',
    img: 'images/dino.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'moon',
    img: 'images/moon.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'rabbit',
    img: 'images/rabbit.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'sun',
    img: 'images/sun.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'tree',
    img: 'images/tree.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'white',
    img: 'images/white.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'cactus',
    img: 'images/cactus.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'dino',
    img: 'images/dino.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'moon',
    img: 'images/moon.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'rabbit',
    img: 'images/rabbit.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'sun',
    img: 'images/sun.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'tree',
    img: 'images/tree.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'white',
    img: 'images/white.png'
  },
]

cardArray.sort(() => 8.5 - Math.random())

const gridDisplay = document.querySelector('#grid')

function createBoard() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const card = document.createElement('img')
    card.setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png')
    card.setAttribute('data-id', i)
    gridDisplay.appendChild(card)
  }
}
createBoard()
```

```css
#grid {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Score: <span id="result"></span></h3>
<div id="grid"> </div>
```

Comment: Typo. Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/). The script needs a `SouRCe` not a `SCReensaver`

Comment: is that a typo?   `scr !== src`

Comment: Note also those as you have them have to be in the same folder - not a best practice for static files

Comment: I added your code to a snippet - just to illustrate it throws no errors.

Comment: I would suggest adding `alt="something"` attributes to images.

Comment: Mate, for future reference, hit `f12` to see the devtools. That'll really help you figure out what's wrong. For example - you could see in the network tab that the script isn't loading at all.

Comment: If this is NOT a typo on `scr="app.js"` please update your question to further clarify your errors.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 <script scr="app.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: FWIW There is a close reason for typo

Answer (score 1):

Change `scr` attribute to `src` in your script import line. and It should be fine.

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: FWIW There is a close reason for typo